# Variables globales o variables de sesión en Symfony2

Tags: symfony2

Buenos días expertos, estoy desarrollando un aplicación en Symfony 2.7 y es multi-empresa, es decir que todas las tablas tienen un ID específico para filtrarse con cualquier request del usuario. Mi pregunta es ¿cual es la mejor práctica para tener disponible el ID de la empresa seleccionada y poder utilizara el controladores o plantillas twig?.

Comment: Actualmente tienes algo desarrollado que nos puedas mostrar o algun diagrama?

Comment: Tengo una tabla de usuarios y una tabla de empresas, el usuario tiene acceso a determinadas empresas, entonces pone sus credenciales y luego la aplicación le solicita seleccionar una empresa (que proviene de una tabla) cuando lo selecciona actualmente estoy pasando a los formularios y controladores el ID de la empresa seleccionada, asi como el nombre de le empresa como parámetros, pero quisiera saber si pueden ser variables internas que puedan utilizarse en cualquier momento, parecido a app.user.

Comment: <a href="{{ path('producto', {'idempresa': idempresa, 'empresa': empresa}) }}" class = "btn btn-warning">regresar</a>